# On wikidata SPARQL get coordinates in degree?

Tags: sparql, geospatial, wikidata

I want to get coordinates via SPARQL from wikidata displayed as degrees (e.g. *54°54'36"N*). It is displayed in wikidata like this, so I suspect there is a built-in function for this purpose but I can not find it.

**Example query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?countryLabel ?long
{
  ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256 ;
           p:P1332 [ psv:P1332 [wikibase:geoLatitude ?long ]].
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

This gives the longitude as number (e.g. *-30.08*). I can calculate the desired output format from this result but would prefer to get it directly from the query.

Thanks.

Comment: there is no built-in function, just compute it by yourself via math operations and use `BIND(MATH_STUFF_HERE as ?var)` to bind the expression

Comment: in Wikidata the HTML stuff is just doing the same and rendering by this template: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Module:Coordinates

Comment: as a starting point, to get the parts for latitude, you can do `SELECT DISTINCT ?country ?countryLabel ?lat ?long ?lat_degrees ?lat_minutes ?lat_seconds
{
  ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256 ;
           p:P1332 [ psv:P1332 [wikibase:geoLatitude ?lat ; wikibase:geoLongitude ?long ]].
  BIND(floor(?lat) as ?lat_degrees)
  BIND((?lat - ?lat_degrees) * 60 as ?rest1)
  BIND(floor(?rest1) as ?lat_minutes)
  BIND((?rest1 - ?lat_minutes) * 60 as ?rest2)
  BIND(floor(?rest2) as ?lat_seconds)
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
} `

Comment: indeed you have to decide on `N` or `S` and do the same for longitude and concatenate all parts to the final string